# sqlite3.cursor.execute не выполняет запорос на вставку из другой таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

В БД есть таблица(1), в которую надо записать значение из другой таблицы(2) этой же БД. В программе пользователь выбирает из `listbox` `id` записи которую надо занести из 2 в 1.

Часть кода который я написал и, как вы могли догадаться, он не работает. Ошибок не выдает, просто не выполняется запрос:

```
tir = #число, просто число 
query1 = f'Insert Into toto Select *,{tir} From matches where match_id= {lis.get(lis.curselection())[0]}'
cur.execute(query1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `cur.execute(query1)` - выполняет запрос, но не читает возвращенные записи автоматически.
2. SQL команда `INSERT` ничего не возвращает - она просто вставляет записи в таблицу.
3. я переписал запрос с использованием параметризированных значений дабы избежать рисков, связанных с [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
4. Не забывайте зафиксировать DML при помощи команды `COMMIT`
5. Чтобы просмотреть результат вставки можно вычитать записи из таблицы `toto`
6. Если вы все еще не видите новых записей в таблице `toto`, значит подзапрос `Select *, ? From matches where match_id= ?` не вернул ни одной записи и вставлять соответственно было нечего.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

cur = conn.cursor()
# ...

tir = #число, просто число 
query1 = f'Insert Into toto Select *, ? From matches where match_id= ?'
params = [tir, lis.get(lis.curselection())[0]]
cur.execute(query1, params)
conn.commit()

# читаем из `toto`
cur.execute("select * from toto")
records = list(cur.fetchall())
```